# Can anyone interpret this C++ code (from OpenJDK6) into plain English?

Tags: c++, jvm, java-native-interface, java, compare-and-swap

Here's a code snippet from [OpenJDK6's `hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/hotspot/file/a541ca8fa0e3/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp) (starting on line 1082):

```
// JSR166 ------------------------------------------------------------------

UNSAFE_ENTRY(jboolean, Unsafe_CompareAndSwapObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject unsafe, jobject obj, jlong offset, jobject e_h, jobject x_h))
  UnsafeWrapper("Unsafe_CompareAndSwapObject");
  oop x = JNIHandles::resolve(x_h);
  oop e = JNIHandles::resolve(e_h);
  oop p = JNIHandles::resolve(obj);
  HeapWord* addr = (HeapWord *)index_oop_from_field_offset_long(p, offset);
  if (UseCompressedOops) {
    update_barrier_set_pre((narrowOop*)addr, e);
  } else {
    update_barrier_set_pre((oop*)addr, e);
  }
  oop res = oopDesc::atomic_compare_exchange_oop(x, addr, e);
  jboolean success  = (res == e);
  if (success)
    update_barrier_set((void*)addr, x);
  return success;
UNSAFE_END
```

The key method **oopDesc::atomic_compare_exchange_oop** is added also.

```
 inline oop oopDesc::atomic_compare_exchange_oop(oop exchange_value,
                                                    volatile HeapWord *dest,
                                                    oop compare_value) {
      if (UseCompressedOops) {
        // encode exchange and compare value from oop to T
        narrowOop val = encode_heap_oop(exchange_value);
        narrowOop cmp = encode_heap_oop(compare_value);

        narrowOop old = (narrowOop) Atomic::cmpxchg(val, (narrowOop*)dest, cmp);
        // decode old from T to oop
        return decode_heap_oop(old);
      } else {
        return (oop)Atomic::cmpxchg_ptr(exchange_value, (oop*)dest, compare_value);
      }
    }
```

What is the purpose of this code in the context of the JVM? I'm not experienced in C++.

**Atomic::cmpxchg & Atomic::cmpxchg_ptr** becomes OS & CPU &  32bit/64bit dependent. So JVMs are splitted here.

**EDIT**

As steve-O pointed out, CAS has its weakness as ABA problem, so memory barrier is necessary here to ensure the CAS is still correct in multithread environment. Also as CAS would need three paramter the address,old value and new value,so modern CPU is required for this process.

**EDIT**

With the new [C++0x standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x) (not formal published now?) , does it mean that JVM don't need to be spliited then? At least, in the source code level. The binary could be still splitted but it will be handled by the C++ compiler.

Comment: Maybe I should pick up a C++ book ten years ago and read it again to remember the C++ grammer so I can understand it in code level.:)Also thanks for the edit of In_silico, it looks much cleaner.

Comment: Steve-o's answer looks very interesting to me. Because he's explaining from an angle of C++ world while I am from java. So we are from different angles to look into it.

Comment: For complete wiki about HotSpotInternals   http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a JNI wrapper for the [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) API, with [memory barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) for [IA64 architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ia64).

**edit:** for a description of CAS:

Compare *dest* with *compare value* and if they match assign *exchange value* to *dest*.

It is an [atomic operation](http://wiki.osdev.org/Atomic_operation) which means no other processor can change the value of *dest* whilst the operation executes.

Typical problems that can occur without atomic operations are listed here, the "ABA problem"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem

**Why would you use a CAS function?**

Easy example is a counter, if you have multiple threads incrementing a counter consider what the increment process does:

```
int i;
read the value of i
add one to the current value
save the value back to i.
```

What happens when another processor reads the value of *i* and saves *i + 1* before this processor has completed?

You end up with *i + 1* instead of *i + 2*.

Comment: Should this be general usage and can be used on all CPUs or platform? I only find this which is the JNI wrapper for the CompareAndSwapObject method of UnSafe Class.

Comment: @Clark this code in itself is portable, you would have to check the implementations of `oopDesc::atomic_compare_exchange_oop`, etc for additional restrictions.

Comment: @Clark `Atomic::cmpxchg` has platform requirements, for example on x86 at least a 486 processor is required.

Comment: I think I am satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some interprets about

- What's an oop, and why should they be compressed?

An "oop", or "ordinary object pointer" in HotSpot parlance is a managed pointer to an object. It is normally the same size as a native machine pointer, which means 64 bits on an LP64 system. On an ILP32 system, there is a maximum heap size of somewhat less than 4Gb, which is not enough for many applications.

- Which oops are compressed?

In an ILP32-mode JVM, or if the UseCompressedOops flag is turned off in LP64 mode, all oops are the native machine word size.

If UseCompressedOops is true, the following oops in the heap will be compressed:

•the klass field of every object
•every oop instance field
•every element of an oop array (objArray)

For details, looks into this [sun wiki](http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops)